# CL.EXE (v8.00c) produces an "Out of memory" error when compiling files

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, compiler-errors, bootloader

I'm building the bootloader from [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/36907/how-to-develop-your-own-boot-loader). The downloadable file contains source code for a bootloader and a patched version of `CL.EXE`, `ML.EXE` and `LINK.EXE`.

When `CL.EXE` is run it displays:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 8.00c
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993. All rights reserved.
>
> bootmain.cpp
>
> Out of memory

The `%errorlevel%` return value 2. The file is not compiled to an object file when the `Out of memory` error occurs.

Note: I'm using version 8.00c of `CL.EXE` that was part of Visual C++ 1.52c which was the last version of the Visual C++ compiler that could produce 16-bit executables and binaries.

---

If I reduce `BootMain.cpp` to this minimal file:

```
extern "C" void BootMain()
{
    return;
}
```

I still get an `Out of Memory` error when I compile it to an object file with:

```
.\VC152\CL.EXE /AT /G2 /Gs /Gx /c /Zl BootMain.cpp
```

Comment: What system are you compiling on, and how little memory does it have?  Are you running an ancient version of CL.exe inside DOSBox or some other emulator configured to emulate a machine with not much RAM?

Comment: Windows 10 x64, 4GB of memory (8GB virtual memory). Toolkits are from (https://www.codeproject.com/articles/36907/how-to-develop-your-own-boot-loader)

Comment: CL 8.00 is from Visual C++ 1.52 I think, the last 16 bits version. And Windows x64 can't run 16 bits executables (32 bits Windows can still run 16 bits executables, and 64 bits Windows can run 32 bits executables, but this is too far back)

Comment: @MSalters but i'm not having to executing it... I only executable in virtual machine, or using DOSBox instead.

Comment: @winapiadmin: But there's no way that DOSBox can use that 8 GB of virtual memory. I think CL.EXE can use EMS memory - we need to know the inside details of the DOSBox environment, not the Windows host.

Comment: Yes. MS-DOS 5.0 using only maximum memory: 640 KB only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some antiquated tools can't handle long environment variables like `PATH` or `INCLUDE` which can become unwieldly in modern Windows development environments. Your `CL.EXE` happens to be a Win32 PE executable so should run on even 64-bit Windows as a 32-bit application. Since `CL.EXE` worked for me in [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) I had to assume there was some external factor for the `Out of Memory` error when run directly on Windows. My first thought was the environment variables so I reduced mine to the bare minimum.

As an experiment one could temporarily put these commands in `BUILD.BAT` at the beginning to see if environment variables are a problem:

```
set PATH=
set INCLUDE=
```

If this solves your problem you may wish to put these lines at the top of your `BUILD.BAT` to save the old environment variables and use empty ones:

```
@set OLDINC=%INCLUDE%
@set OLDPATH=%PATH%
@set PATH=
@set INCLUDE=
```

To restore these environment variables place these lines at the end:

```
@set INCLUDE=%OLDINC%
@set PATH=%OLDPATH%
@set OLDINC=
@set OLDPATH=
```

---

### Miscellaneous

- If you want `LINK.EXE` to stop prompting you unnecessarily for information place a `;` (semicolon) at the end of the linker command line to force it to use default values. It would look like:

  ```
  .\VC152\LINK.EXE /T /NOD StartPoint.obj bootmain.obj cdisplay.obj cstring.obj;
  ```
- An `@` at the beginning of a batch file line suppresses the command being echoed to standard output (ie. console)